# some practical uses of mem_fn & bind

Tags: c++, stdbind, tr1, mem-fun

Can someone recommend some cool practical uses of tr1's mem_fn and bind utilities? I don't need esoteric c++ for library development. just some application level coding which makes uses of these.

any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I have used `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind` for reflection style properties.

So I would have a `class SomeClass` with a vector of `AbstractProperty`. There can be several different types of classes from `AbstractProperty`, such as `PropertyFloat`, `PropertyU32`, etc.

Then in `SomeClass` I will `bind` to a `std::function` for `AbstractProperty`. I would `bind` by doing

```
std::bind(std::mem_fn(&SomeClass::SomeFloatGetter), this)
```

For a setter type function, I would use

```
 std::bind(std::mem_fn(&SomeClass::SomeSetterGetter), this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

Of course, to set the functions to the class is more difficult, but I do use a `std::function` to do so. In `PropertyFloat` I have

```
typedef std::function<float(void)> GetterType;
```

So it set it via a function, I would pass the first `std::bind` I showed as the parameter for

```
typename PropertyFloat::GetterType getter
```

Of course, the types could make use of templates and be more generic, but that is a trade off depending on what you are developing for.

Comment: +1. That is the kind of thing I want to try too. You have more details to share on how you did the reflection bit?

Comment: Hmm, this was basically the most I could describe without probably putting up the entire codebase on github or something (and the code is closed source). I updated my post to provide more details though. Unfortunately, there is not a lot of documentation for the type of system I developed here. I am in the process of writing a large document on the entire system, but its not quite finished yet. I can say I have been using `std::mem_fn` and `std::bind` for this kind of thing for nearly two years though with no problems.

Comment: Also not, that this is one of the most complex usages of `mem_fn` and `bind` that I know of. If you are looking to get practice using the two types, perhaps you should look at some small usages of them (I did at first before I developed this system). This reflection system is built around the use of these two types (and `std::function`). Although honestly, this may be able to be just replaced with member function pointers (in theory). They both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 5):

Normally it can be quite a hassle to use member functions for callbacks, for example for use in the `<algorithm>` functions. `std::mem_fn` (it's been standardized now, so you shouldn't need to use the `tr1` namespace anymore) creates a callable object that can be used as the functor object of those functions. For an example of its use, see the examples section of [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) which uses `std::string::size`.

`std::bind` can be used when e.g. you don't know the actual arguments at compile-time, but have to create a callable object with arguments runtime. It can also be used to reorder arguments, example:

```
auto f1 = std::bind(printf, _2, _1);
f1(42, "%d\n");
```

(Okay, stupid example, but all I could think of right now.)

Answer (score 4):

The following code counts the number of elements greater than five:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<int> v { 1, 5, 2, 7, 6, 7, 5 };
  cout << count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                   bind(greater<int>(), placeholders::_1, 5)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why should bind be a better choice than a lambda function in this example?

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that lambdas have difficulty using methods from forward declared classes. I've used bind to make use of member functions that use methods from a forward declared class. I couldn't find a solution that used lambdas. Here was the scenario: I had a list of member functions, f1, f2, ... defined in class A, some of which used methods from a forward declared class. I wanted to be able to flexibly swap out operators of the nodes of an expression tree, class B, with any one of these fi functions. In B, a generic operator was defined. I used bind to associate the fi functions to the generic operator adaptively. That way, the fi member function definitions could be prototyped in a  A.h file where the forward declaration was put, then the implementations for the fi functions could be put in the A.cpp file and accessed by B class.  I'd be curious if others have run into this issue and how they dealt with it.